# Load directshow filter from file using DSPack

Tags: delphi, directshow, dspack

How can I load a DirectShow filter not registered by an .ax file in delphi 7 using DSPack?
I found [an example in C++](http://www.gdcl.co.uk/2011/June/UnregisteredFilters.htm), I do not know how to translate it into Delphi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here you go](https://github.com/Wraits/Cameta/blob/5df8bd0d27f9ef08aa06fa354c8309d35a223141/Cameta_Utils.pas#L2055):

```
function LoadFilter(const Fhandle: HMODULE; clis: TGUID): IBaseFilter; overload;
Var
  DllGetClassObject: Function(Const clsid, IID: TGUID; Var Obj)
    : HRESULT; STDCALL;
  ClassF: IClassFactory;
Begin
  result := nil;
  try
    If Fhandle = 0 Then
      exit;
    // NOTE: Fhandle is typically obtained as a result of LoadLibrary API
    //       call loading DLL hosting the DirectShow filter
    DllGetClassObject := GetProcAddress(Fhandle, 'DllGetClassObject');
    DllGetClassObject(clis, IClassFactory, ClassF);
    if assigned(ClassF) then
    begin
      if ClassF.CreateInstance(nil, IID_IBaseFilter, result) = ERROR_SUCCESS
      then
        exit;
    end;
  except
    exit;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: To compile exit () must be exit, and the ax file must be loaded with the LoadLibrary function, it's possible add the filter to the graph `(CaptureGraph as IFilterGraph).AddFilter(Filter,'Name');`